# Equation only taking one value for a instead of a list and producing a list

Tags: r

I have a list with 92516 values for a; when i try to enter it in the below formula i only receive 1 value instead of a list of 92516 values.

```
c = 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a))) # outputs only 1 value

c = 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a[1:92516])))
```

> Error in a[1:92516, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Could you please provide a small reproducible example.  What is the `str(a)`  Perhaps you need `sqrt(unlist(a))`

Comment: If the input is a list, another option would be `c = lapply(a, function(x) 2* asin(min(1, sqrt(x))))`.

Comment: @LeoP. Much appreciated - managed to complete using lapply. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: @Farah You are welcome!

Comment: using `sapply` instead of `lapply` may suit you even better

Comment: Actually,  the real problem here is that you should use `pmin`,  not `min`.  Take a look at the help page `?min` which describes both.

Comment: @G5W - Fantastic that also worked - thanks for the help!